# Check checkboxes using array of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

The user can provide an array of string and I want to look in a table and check the assosiated checkbox with the table row when one of the string is found.

I can see that the `$("#activelisttable tr:contains(" + substr[i] + ")")` contains a `<tr>` but it simply dosen't go in the `.each` function.

Here is the full code :

```
     $("#savelistactive").click(function() {
            var substr = $("#listtextactive").val().split("\n");
            for (var i = 0; i < substr.length; i++) 
            {
                $("#activelisttable tr:contains(" + substr[i] + ")").each(function(item) {
                    $(this).children("input").prop('checked', true);
                });
            }
            $("#background").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#listactive").fadeOut("slow");
        });
```

Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/5WVwe/

Comment: You're missing a closing curly bracket on the `for` loop `}`...

Comment: typo error. It was there in the code edited it thx :)

Comment: No worries. Add these two console statements `console.log(substr.length);` and inside the `for` loop add `console.log($("#activelisttable tr:contains(" + substr[i] + ")").length);` What are these two values?

Comment: Is this working now ? If not, please post the corresponding HTML and if possible a fiddle.

Comment: Can you try not using `.each()` and see what `$("#activelisttable tr:contains(" + substr[i] + ")").children("input").prop('checked', true);` does?

Comment: also try adding quotes for the  `tr:contains('" + substr[i] + "')`

Comment: added the fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem Recap:

The problem is with your selector inside the `for` loop. *@NobleMushtak* recommended that you change the `.each()` in your [original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WVwe/) to be:

```
$("#activelisttable tr:contains(" + substr[i] + ")").children("input").prop('checked', true);
```

This was a good suggestion. However, having not seen your markup, it was unclear the exact HTML structure you were using. According to your fiddle, your HTML markup contains `<tr>`'s which then contain `<th>`'s within them:

```
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" class="selectall" />
            </th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
```

This means that there are no `.children()` of the `<tr>`'s with a type of `input`.

### Solution:

Change `.children()` to be `.find()`:

```
$("#activelisttable tr:contains(" + substr[i] + ")").find("input").prop('checked', true);
```

`.find()` does a deep search of *all* nested elements versus `.children()` which will only traverse down one more layer.

Works great with the change.

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/5WVwe/1/)

**Reference Documentation:**

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)